# Complete Network Fail

Tags: 14.04, networking

On a dark & stormy night is when the nightmare started. Power flickered and my laptop(Dead Batt) went off.. when I turn it back on it connected back to the network (eth0) but there is nothing.. cant ping in to it or out to wan or lan. Ifconfig looks right.

I do have apache running on it and the service is running. but can not even open it in firefox using 127.0.0.1. My router is seeing the laptop is conneted and fire walls is off.
Ready? 
set. 
GO!

Thanks in advance.